# Cannot connect to Neo4j 3.5.14 Community Edition server

Tags: neo4j, centos, graph-databases

Good day,

I have been trying to connect to Neo4j 3.5.14 community edition on my server but I have not been able.

I installed a fresh version of neo4j on my namecheap centos7 vps yesterday.

neo4j 3.5.14
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)

Below is my config file:

```
#*****************************************************************
# Network connector configuration
#*****************************************************************

# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
#dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=199.192.xxx.xxx

# You can also choose a specific network interface, and configure a non-default
# port for each connector, by setting their individual listen_address.

# The address at which this server can be reached by its clients. This may be the server's IP address or DNS name, or
# it may be the address of a reverse proxy which sits in front of the server. This setting may be overridden for
# individual connectors below.
#dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=localhost
dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=199.192.xxx.xxx

# You can also choose a specific advertised hostname or IP address, and
# configure an advertised port for each connector, by setting their
# individual advertised_address.

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=199.192.xxx.xxx:7687

# HTTP Connector. There can be zero or one HTTP connectors.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=199.192.xxx.xxx:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473
```

Below is my netstat result:

```
tcp6       0      0 199.192.xxx.xxx:7687     :::*                    LISTEN      4205/java
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      5117/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2951/httpd
tcp6       0      0 199.192.xxx.xxx:7473     :::*                    LISTEN      4205/java
tcp6       0      0 199.192.xxx.xxx:7474     :::*                    LISTEN      4205/java
```

Each time I try to access: 199.192.xxx.xxx:7473,

I get **This site cannot be reached**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to access it via HTTPS, but dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473 is commented out in the config file